# Consulta: Ejercicio, llenar arrays con números random sin que se repita ninguno

Tags: java, array, condiciones

Tengo un problema actualmente, un algoritmo que me han mandado a hacer en la facultad sin explicarme absolutamente nada, y que revisando guías y tal, no he logrado entender cómo hacer el asunto.
El enunciado es el siguiente:

> Desarrollar un algoritmo en Java que cargue un arreglo de tamaño **n** con números aleatorios. El arreglo no debe contener números repetidos, indique en cuántos intentos se cargó el arreglo.

El ejercicio la verdad que es fácil, solo tengo ese pequeño problema, el hacer que escoja los números al azar es solo una línea de código, pero la parte de evitar que hayan números repetidos es la que no sé cómo hacer; y si no me equivoco, para calcular el número de intentos simplemente debo usar un contador dentro del ciclo, es lo que creo.

Si alguien puede echarme una mano con esta parte se lo agradecería :D

Comment: Percibo que has intentado a buen ritmo y por eso aquí mi comentario: Un tip: mete todos los números randoms en un arreglo y en cada iteración pregunta si ese número existe. Ahora bien, esperamos que edites tu pregunta agregando el código que tienes. Saludos y bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español.

Comment: @fredyfx el problema es ese, en teoría no me han dado ni una clase de Java, lo que sé es por ejercicios que mandan y que he investigado, me podrías decir cómo realizar esa pregunta?

Comment: un if statement :D

Answer (score 0):

Cuando vaya a insertar el numero que se genera aleatoriamente, puede recorrer el array para verificar si el numero a insertar se encuentra, de ser asi no ingrese el numero en su lugar genere otra vez un numero aleatorio y repita la operacion hasta que el numero no se encuentre solo si se cumple esa condicion agrege el numero.